# How to set the checkbox setSelected() of child components using getComponent()

Tags: java, swing, list, jcheckbox

I'm trying to set all the checkboxes' value to `setSelected(false)`. These checkboxes are from different subpanels that has other subpanels. `getComponents(panelName)` only gets the components contained on it but not every subpanel/child panel of child panel... and so on.

[image]

In the above,`allPermissionsJPanel` is the parent panel. `settingsButtonPanel` and `cardContainerPanel` as first level subpanel and I want every single `JCheckBox` to be set to false.

How do I do that? I tried using `getComponents()` but it's not returning all the checkboxes from subpanel of subpanels.

This is my code.

```
List<Component> allPermissionsCheckboxes =fm.getComponentsAsList(allPermissionsJPanel);


        for(Component c: allPermissionsCheckboxes){
            if(c instanceof JCheckBox){
                ((JCheckBox) c).setSelected(false);
            }
        }
```

I tried checking other methods related to `getComponents()` but I didn't find a method that goes through every subpanel of subpanel so I can check if it's an `instanceof` a `JCheckBox`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CubeJockey, thanks. Yours got approved, tho.  Strange.

Comment: @BPS, Yes, once you reach the 2k rep limit, your edits do not enter the suggestion queue and are automatically approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to implement this as a recursive method that iterates through the component hierarchy looking for check boxes and performing `setSelected(false)`.

The method could look something like this:

```
public void deselectAllCheckBoxes(Component panel) {
    List<Component> allComponents = fm.getComponentsAsList(panel);

    for (Component c : allComponents) { // Loop through all the components in this panel
        if (c instanceof JCheckBox) { // if a component is a check box, uncheck it.
            ((JCheckBox) c).setSelected(false);
        } else if (c instanceof JPanel) { // if a component is a panel, call this method
            deselectAllCheckBoxes(c);     // recursively.
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is call `deselectAllCheckBoxes(allPermissionsPanel);`

Comment: Recursion per your advice fixed my problem. Thanks. It was helpful.